# Does $\kappa \lt \lambda$ implie $cf\kappa \lt cf\lambda$ for singular cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In T. Jech's set theory, the part which he tries to prove a part of silver's theorem on the singular cardinal hypothesis, namely, 
 "If the singular cardinal hypothesis holds for all singular cardinals of cofinality $\omega$, then it holds for all singular cardinals."
 Is confusing me a little bit. He assumes that $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal of uncountable cofinality and he uses induction on the cofinality of $\kappa$ to prove the statement. The part which i am struggling to understand is where he says that for each $\lambda \lt \kappa$ we have $\lambda^{cf\kappa} \lt \kappa$. I know that assuming the singular cardinal hypothesis $\lambda^{cf\kappa}$ is either $2^{cf\kappa}$ or $\lambda$ or $\lambda^{+}$ based on the continuum and cofinality functions. So if induction on the cofinality of $\kappa$ is the same as induction on singular cardinals then i can assume that the singular cardinal hypothesis holds bellow $\kappa$ and i'm fine. So the question is: 
Does $\kappa \lt \lambda$ implie $cf\kappa \lt cf\lambda$ for singular cardinals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Recall that if $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\delta)=\operatorname{cf}(\delta)$.

Now take $\kappa=\aleph_{\omega_1}$ and $\lambda=\aleph_{\omega_1+\omega}$.

---

As for the proof of Silver's theorem, note that if $\lambda<\kappa$, by induction on $\lambda$, and using both your assumption and Hausdorff's formula to obtain that $\lambda^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}<\kappa$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, so how can i go about proving that statement then?

Comment: I added something, and I hope it will help.

Comment: How can i use my induction hypothesis for limit $\lambda$?

Comment: (A side question: how do you put that horizontal line in your answer?)

Comment: For limit $\lambda$ we can say that since each $v^{cf\kappa}$ , $v \lt \lambda$, is less than $\kappa$ then their suprema,$\lambda^{cf\kappa}$, is less than or equal to $\kappa$. How can i refute the equality?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time to give you an answer off hand with full details. I think that it would be best if you post a separate question . As for the horizontal line, `---` three dashes in a separate line would create that. I also recommend paragraph breaks (which are two consecutive line breaks), as they make reading much easier, and this question of yours is kind of hard on the eyes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.